# Does the Cayley-Menger determinant for a tetrahedron being positive, along with the triangle inequality holding, imply Ptolemy's inequality.

Tags: metric-spaces, euclidean-geometry, simplex

I was confused after finding out, by computing counterexamples, that the Cayley-Menger determinant for a tetrahedron being positive does not actually imply that the triangle inequality and Ptolemy's inequality holds for all points, since I assumed that being a representation of the volume meant that all positive values for any 3-dimensional CM determinant would lead to a set of distances for points that could be realised as a tetrahedron in Euclidean 3D space.

Therefore, I decided to try to find examples of the 8 different cases: one in which Ptolemy's inequality holds but the triangle inequality does not and the Cayley-Menger determinant is negative, one in which both Ptolemy's inequality and the triangle inequality holds but Cayley-Menger determinant is negative and so on.

I ended up finding examples of each type except for one case: The Cayley-Menger determinant is positive and the triangle inequality holds but Ptolemy's inequality does not hold. This leads me to believe that, together, the Cayley-Menger determinant being positive and the triangle inequality holding for all points implies that Ptolemy's inequality holds.

I have tried to find proofs of Ptolemy's inequality that rely both on the triangle inequality and the volume of a tetrahedron being positive but have not found any. I have also attempted to prove it to no avail. I feel like there would be an elegant proof of this using matrices, since Ptolemy's inequality holding is equivalent to the (1,1) minor of the 3-Dimensional CM determinant being negative, but I have failed to find one.

Disclaimer: this is a different question to the one I made a few days ago (one which was disproved by one of the counterexamples mentioned)

Comment: I just had a look (through a Google book access, in particular Chapter 5) at the very recent "Handbook of Geometric Constraint (Systems Principles)" by Meera Sitharam, Audrey St. John, Jessica Sidman [CRC Press] (2018) that looks very pertinent for your interesting questionning.

Comment: I just saw that you have re-posted the same question that you had posted 2 days ago (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3347979) with very slight modifications. **It isn't a fair way to use this site** for different reasons you surely are aware of. Instead, you should have modified your first version.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Ptolemy's inequality and the triangle inequality together imply the Cayley-Menger determinant for a tetrahedron is positive?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3347979/does-ptolemys-inequality-and-the-triangle-inequality-together-imply-the-cayley)

Comment: Oh, no, that is my other question and it is almost the converse of this one. One of the counterexamples I mentioned in this question disproves that.

Comment: The least you should have done is to mention this previous question and the difference between their problematics.

Comment: Okay, well I have deleted the other question since it has been answered by the counterexample..

Comment: Another interesting pointer, paper [Edge lengths determine tetrahedrons by Wirth and Dreiding](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Edge-lengths-determining-tetrahedrons-Wirth-Dreiding/dd9f045a9c0b8d4ba3487e56aa632a3185f2a707)